# Regex for consecutive repeated word in R

Tags: r

Regular expression to find words and digits  that are repeated back to back

Suppose I have a data frame

```
df<-data.frame(name=c("mike","mike","mike","bob","mike"),age=c(23,23,23,25,23)
```

how can I write a regular expression to check "name" column whether "mike" or any other word  is repeated back to bake for e.g here mike is repeated 3 times and in "age" column a digit is repeated e.g here 23 is repeated 3 times back to back

Comment: What is your expected output for this example?

Comment: @RonakShah the value of repeated words or digits
like below:
 name="mike","mike","mike"
age=23,23,23

Comment: So subset rows if both the columns are repeated atleast 3 times. If any one of them is not repeated (if 23 is only twice) you don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = data.table::rleid, .names = '{col}_grp')) %>%
  group_by(across(ends_with('grp'))) %>%
  filter(n() >= 3) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(names(df))

#  name    age
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 mike     23
#2 mike     23
#3 mike     23
```

For every column in `df` we use `rleid` to give a unique number to consecutive values and select those groups that have `>= 3` rows in them.

Answer (score 0):

Base R one liner (no regex):

```
df[which(c(0, cumsum(abs(diff(as.integer(as.factor(df$name)))))) == 0),]
```